azure pipeline fails when trying to upload ios app to testflight

My azure pipeline file as follows
trigger:
  - test-nj

jobs:
  - job: ios
    pool:
      vmImage: 'macOS-latest'
    variables:
      - name: configuration
        value: "Release"
      - name: sdk
        value: "iphoneos"
      - name: scheme
        value: "Runner"
      - name: system.debug
        value: true

    steps:
      - task: FlutterInstall@0
        displayName: "Install Flutter SDK"
        inputs:
          mode: 'auto'
          channel: 'stable'
          version: 'latest'

      - task: FlutterBuild@0
        displayName: "Flutter Build Apps - iOS"
        inputs:
          target: "ios"
          buildName: "$(Build.BuildNumber)"
          entryPoint: "lib/main.dart"
          iosCodesign: false

      - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
        inputs:
          certSecureFile: 'appCertificate.p12'
          certPwd: $(appCertificatePassword)
          keychain: 'temp'
          deleteCert: true
 
      - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
        inputs:
          provProfileSecureFile: 'app.mobileprovision'
          removeProfile: true

      - task: Xcode@5
        inputs:
          actions: 'build'
          scheme: '$(scheme)'
          sdk: '$(sdk)'
          configuration: '$(configuration)'
          xcWorkspacePath: '**/ios/Runner.xcworkspace'
          xcodeVersion: 'default'
          signingOption: 'manual'
          signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
          provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
          packageApp: true
 
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          contents: '**/*.ipa'
          targetFolder: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
          overWrite: true
          flattenFolders: true

      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          pathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)'
          artifactName: 'drop'
          publishLocation: 'Container'
          
      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: "listing copied files"
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
            ls  $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/

      - task: AppStoreRelease@1
        inputs:
          serviceEndpoint: 'abc'
          releaseTrack: 'TestFlight'
          appIdentifier: 'com.abc.cde'
          appType: 'iOS'
          ipaPath: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/abc.ipa'
          shouldSkipWaitingForProcessing: true
          shouldSkipSubmission: true
          appSpecificId: '12345678'
          installFastlane: true
          additionalFastlaneArgs: '--verbose'

I tried changing the AppStoreRelease@1 step but nothing works.

We can't see the full error message from the pipeline logs.

Hi there, May I know if the local deployment works, and does the pipeline work before? What other error message can be seen in the debug logs expect for failed with exit code 1? What was changed compared to the last successful deployment? In your code or in the pipeline?

AppStoreRelease@1 task keep getting failed....can you give  me some instructions about how to configure it

The concern in this post is more like an issue troubleshooting rather than a how-to query. I am not sure if the guidance on the extension task in this document can resolve your specific issue. And I am afraid with the current information that shared, we are unable to locate what could have caused the error or reproduce the same.
